# posicionar varios divs flotantes alineados en un contenedor

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy aprendiendo y necesito dinámicamente cargar varias imágenes, puede ser 1 o 50 , en el ejemplo hice un bucle corto con varios divs flotantes para explicar mi problema. Necesito que los divs se vean alineados con el mismo espacio exacto unos de otros , los divs tienen ancho y alto fijos ( cargaré imagenes dentro) y la idea es que si achico el browser se recalculen los espacios o margenes horizontales entre ellos, o sea entren los que quepan , queden centrados , y que los que no quepan pasen a una segunda linea dentro del contenedor, alineados igual que la primera.
Quizás no es la forma y deba utilizar jquery o javascript, necesitaría un ejemplo para arrancar, estudiarlo y adaptarlo.

El código para index.php:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="css/estilo.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="contenedor">
  <?php 
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
     ?>
      <div class="marcos">
       <div class="fotos"></div>
      </div>
  <?php
   }
  ?>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

la hoja de estilos :

```css
* {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}

body {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: auto;
}

#contenedor {
 max-width: 910px;
 min-width: 240px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.marcos {
 float:left;
 width: 180px;
 height: 220px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.fotos {
 text-align: center; 
 margin: 9px 9px;
 width: 160px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El uso de `flexbox` puede servirte. [Aquí hay un Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpv7qsn9/) con unas modificaciones que hice a tu código.

En resumen, modifiqué el CSS de `#contenedor`

```
#contenedor {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /* ... Los demás atributos se mantienen igual */
}
```

En CSS-Tricks hay [información sobre flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), con esquemas y ejemplos. Funciona bien en navegadores modernos, como se detalla en [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
        * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#contenedor {
  max-width: 700px;
  min-width: 240px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.marcos {
  width: 180px;
  height: 220px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.fotos {
  margin: 9px 9px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
 <div id="contenedor">
    <?php 
         for($i=1; $i<10; $i++){
          $html ='
                <div class="marcos">
                  <div class="fotos"></div>
                </div>';
           echo $html;
          }
         
      ?>
  </div>
```

**Asi se ejecutara**